# cannot find log produced by sample php elastic beanstalk web application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I decided to play with Amazon AWS and created a PHP application on Elastic Beanstalk. I went with the sample application which is automatically created for you.
My instance started fine, I could see the sample website but I also noticed the sample php file had another functionality: if you would send a POST request it would log it in a file.

[image]

This would be saved to /tmp/sample-app.log.

So I used curl to send some POST requests to my application (ie. curl -X POST )
Then I used putty to log into the EC2 instance associated to the Beanstalk instance (by creating a key pair) and looked in the /tmp folder, there was no sample-app.log.
Actually I did a search in / for all files ending with log and I couldn't find sample-app.log.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the response of the `file_put_contents` method in a variable and check for errors, i.e.

```php
$error = file_put_contents(...);
if (!$error) {
   // report or log error here
}
```

The method [returns false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) on errors.

I think it is a permission issue, but I can't really tell without any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try the whole thing again. Setting a key pair will result in reprovisioning. This is now a new EC2 instance, so you won't find the file from before in it.